# How add cpu frequency that should be available?

Tags: 12.04, hardware, intel, cpufreq

I have a system with an Intel Core i7 970 that should be able to run at 3.2 GHz.  I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and installed the cpufreq indicator to be able to change the governor and noticed that I only had frequencies up to 2.0 GHz available to me.  I set to performance and checked with cpufreq-info

```
cpufreq-info -c 0
cpufrequtils 007: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 1.60 GHz - 2.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.00 GHz, 1.86 GHz, 1.73 GHz, 1.60 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.60 GHz and 2.00 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.00 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 2.00 GHz:4.93%, 1.86 GHz:0.03%, 1.73 GHz:0.02%, 1.60 GHz:95.02%  (718654)
```

And to double check:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies 
1995000 1862000 1729000 1596000
```

How do I get all the frequencies that I should have available to me, all up to the 3.2 GHz?

Comment: Usually cpu frequencies are handled by the BIOS, so there is probably some sort of cap there, look at the clock timings, and see if you have to manually specify a speed (I had to manually state my RAM was 1866)

Comment: Yes that was it apparently the BIOS limited the the multiplier to 15x when it could have gone all the way to 25x.  Fixed and now I am getting all the speeds I should be.

Comment: @AndrewRedd Great! Now, please consider adding this as an answer to your question and select it as the answer to the question. Otherwise people will attempt to answer an already answered question. Apart from the fact that it should help future readers determining the solution more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU frequency is handled by your BIOS, not by the OS (usually), adjusting either the vcore, the base multiplier, etc. (varies depending on the BIOS) should give you the speeds that you are looking for.